# What is the jokes in regards to Dragonball Character names?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

While watching the Co-Optional Podcast ([Episode 209. after 1:47:50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsgoqualIAI&t=1h47m50s) when it says "anime thing"), when talking about *Dragonball Fighters* and how Broly and Bardock were the only 2 confirmed to be being released in future TotalBiscuit said that the names sounded like vegetables. in response Dodger said that the names of Saiyans were supposed to be vegetable puns like how the names of Bumla's family were jokes on underwear.

I admit Broly sorta sound like like Brocoli but not sure how Bardock is a joke on a vegetable, nor how Nappa or Goku (or even Kakarot) are jokes either (Gohan might since i know Gohan is sometimes used in Japanese for "food")

So what are these jokes/puns and are they categorized/themed as Dodger said?

Comment: Note that Bulma's name, in Japanese, is pronounced exactly the way they pronounce ["Bloomers"](https://www.google.com/search?q=bloomers). Also, there's the name of her son.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The puns are in japanese. 
Nappa is a japanese term for greens in general. 
Kakarot is carrot. 
Bardock is a japanese root vegetable "Burdock".

For a full list [Origins of character names](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Origins_of_character_names)

And yes, they are categorized as she said.

Comment: just to correct you, Dodger is the girl in the top right of the video. the only guys in the video were TotalBiscuit and Jessie Cox